# UITextField in inputAccessoryView won't becomeFirstResponder

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

I have a view called songInfoView with 3 UITextFields and a UIButton.  I create a temp UITextField in the parent view to bring up the keyboard and assign songInfoView as the inputAccessoryView.  This works as expected.

Then, I try to set a text field in songInfoView as first responder.  The cursor moves to this field, but when I try to type, nothing happens.  I can tap on the text field and type as expected, but I want it to work without having to tap on it.  Am I missing something?  Am I doing this out of order?  Thanks for your help.

```
songInfoView = [[SongInfoViewController alloc]init];
songInfoView.delegate = self;

UITextField *tempTextField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f)];
[self.view addSubview:tempTextField];
[tempTextField setInputAccessoryView:songInfoView.view];
[tempTextField becomeFirstResponder];
[songInfoView.titleTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out myself.  It turns out (I think) that the on screen keyboard (along with it's accessory view) has it's own window.  So, within songInfoView's viewDidAppear method, I had to call

```
[self.view.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Just remember to call this again within the view controller you used to load the keyboard after the keyboard disappears.  Hope this helps someone else down the road.

Comment: You saved my day! I have the same problem after I put my customView into a new `UIWindow`.