# How do I make a PHFComposeBarView control become active in a Swift iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift

As a relative noob to iOS development I'm struggling to make a [PHFComposeBarView](https://github.com/fphilipe/PHFComposeBarView) control become active in my Swift iOS app.

Having squinted at the Obj-C in the [PHFComposeBarView example app](https://github.com/fphilipe/PHFComposeBarView/tree/master/Example) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26059637/171144), I've managed as best I can to translate the basic setup into Swift such that the control is displayed in the main view:

[image]

However, I haven't managed to make the control become active programatically.

I've created a [minimal test case project](https://github.com/liveminds/SwiftPHFComposeBarTest) in Swift 2.0/XCode 7.0 Beta 2 whose ViewController looks like:

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import PHFComposeBarView

class ViewController: UIViewController, PHFComposeBarViewDelegate {

    var composeBar: PHFComposeBarView {
        let viewBounds = self.view.bounds
        let frame = CGRectMake(0.0, viewBounds.size.height - PHFComposeBarViewInitialHeight, viewBounds.size.width, PHFComposeBarViewInitialHeight)
        let composeBarView = PHFComposeBarView(frame: frame)
        composeBarView.delegate = self
        return composeBarView
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView {
        return self.composeBar
    }

    override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        print("viewDidAppear self \(self)")
        print("composeBar.delegate \(self.composeBar.delegate)")
        print("composeBar.textView.delegate \(self.composeBar.textView.delegate)")
        print("composeBar.canBecomeFirstResponder() \(self.composeBar.canBecomeFirstResponder())")
        print("composeBar.textView.canBecomeFirstResponder() \(self.composeBar.textView.canBecomeFirstResponder())")
        let res = self.composeBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        print("composeBar.becomeFirstResponder() \(res)")
        print("composeBar.isFirstResponder() \(self.composeBar.isFirstResponder())")
        print("composeBar.textView.isFirstResponder() \(self.composeBar.textView.isFirstResponder())")
    }

}
```

Console:

```
viewDidAppear self <SwiftPHFComposeBarTest.ViewController: 0x7fe088619d90>
composeBar.delegate Optional(<SwiftPHFComposeBarTest.ViewController: 0x7fe088619d90>)
composeBar.textView.delegate Optional(<PHFDelegateChain: 0x7fe088654850>)
composeBar.canBecomeFirstResponder() true
composeBar.textView.canBecomeFirstResponder() true
composeBar.becomeFirstResponder() false
composeBar.isFirstResponder() false
composeBar.textView.isFirstResponder() false
```

How can it be that `composeBar.canBecomeFirstResponder()` returns `true` but `composeBar.becomeFirstResponder()` returns `false`?

Also, I'm not sure if the delegate being an Optional is a problem.

**EDIT: Updated to include debug output.**

Comment: A quick search for "input accessoryview becomefirstresponder" returned this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19983179/uitextfield-in-inputaccessoryview-wont-becomefirstresponder

Comment: Thanks Philipe. Sadly, adding a `self.view.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()` to the end of my `viewDidAppear()` method makes no difference. I have however noticed that I'm getting different behaviour in iOS 9 beta and iOS 8.3, in that tapping the control does display the keyboard as expected in 8.3 but then crashes with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception when attempting to type a character. I'll see if I can narrow this down to an iOS version issue.

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't seem to be it, the PHFComposeBarView example app works fine in 8.3 and 9.0 beta.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what it could be. Try using a simple text view instead and see if that works and trouble shoot from there. Good luck!

Comment: N.B. Post updated to include debug output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one solution appears to be to [use the storyboard instead](https://github.com/liveminds/SwiftPHFComposeBarTest/tree/storyboard-managed):

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import PHFComposeBarView

class ViewController: UIViewController, PHFComposeBarViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var composeBarView: PHFComposeBarView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        composeBarView.delegate = self
    }

    override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView {
        composeBarView.removeFromSuperview()
        return composeBarView
    }

}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: have you checked tapping 2 times inside the textview once it is open..??
It'll disappear ..